# Does generalized sidelobe canceller (GSC) differs for non-uniform array?

Tags: beamforming, soft-question

As I understand Linear Constraint minimum variance (LCMV) beamforming weights can be expressed as a solution of a convex optimization problem.In this case we have cost a function to optimize and there are some constraint which must be satisfied by the solution. GSC is a framework to rewrite the LCMV problem into a optimization problem, without any constraint. This is done by composing the weights into two orthogonal components, one of which is the derived from the constraint equations.

The question is: Is the above formulation true and thus GSC is valid for non-uniform array if the original LCMV is for non-uniform array.